# Replace column values that match multiple different patterns

Tags: r, dplyr

In the dataframe below:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(notes=c("Positive result","Negative","NEG","POS >2","pOS","Cannot Determine","2.4","3.1","0.2"))

  notes           
  <chr>           
1 Positive result 
2 Negative        
3 NEG             
4 POS >2          
5 pOS             
6 Cannot Determine
7 2.4             
8 3.1             
9 0.2
```

I would like to define a one-liner to replace the entries in the note column that match a pattern. I would have used the ternary operator if there were only two conditions. But here I have 5.

I am looking to replace values in notes with:

1. `could be turned into a double` -> `"3"`
2. `grepl("pos",tolower(notes))` -> `"2"`
3. `grepl("neg",tolower(notes))` -> `"1"`
4. none of the above -> `"0"`

I initially did:

```
df %>%
  mutate(notes=ifelse(grepl("[[:digit:]]+",notes)),"3",notes) %>%  # could be coerced into a double
  mutate(notes=ifelse(grepl("pos",tolower(notes))),"2",notes) %>%  # contains "pos"
  mutate(notes=ifelse(grepl("neg",tolower(notes))),"1",notes) %>%  # contains "neg"
  mutate(notes=ifelse(grepl("3|2|1",tolower(notes))),notes,"0") %>%  # none of the above
  type.convert()
```

**Desired Output**

```
notes           
<dbl>           
1 2 
2 1        
3 1             
4 2          
5 2             
6 0
7 3            
8 3             
9 3
```

Comment: In your condition what is `could be` as there is no stirng

Comment: `2.4` or `3.5` or `1.2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(notes1 = toupper(substr(notes, 1, 3)), 
        notes =case_when(notes1 == "POS" ~ 2, 
                         notes1 == 'NEG' ~ 1, 
                         str_detect(notes, '^[0-9.]+$')~ 3,
                         TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
  select(-notes1)
# A tibble: 9 x 1
#  notes
#  <dbl>
#1     2
#2     1
#3     1
#4     2
#5     2
#6     0
#7     3
#8     3
#9     3
```

---

If we need to keep the numeric values as such, one option is `as.numeric` and then `coalesce`

```
df %>% 
 mutate(notes1 = toupper(substr(notes, 1, 3)), 
      notes2 =case_when(notes1 == "POS" ~ 2, 
                       notes1 == 'NEG' ~ 1, 
                       str_detect(notes, '^[0-9.]+$')~ 3,
                       TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
 select(-notes1) %>% 
 mutate(notes = coalesce(as.numeric(notes), notes2)) %>% 
 select(-notes2)
```

Comment: One other question! In the framework above, would be be possible to set any of the values that could be turned into a double and are greater than `1.0` to `2` (which encodes positive)?

Comment: @user171558 you meant instead of 3, it should be 2

Comment: If that double is greater than `1.0`, make it a 2. and if lower make it a 1.
something like this:
`ifelse(as.numeric(notes)>=1.0, "2","1")`

Comment: @user171558 values 7  and 8 i.e. 2.4 and 3.1 to 2?

Comment: Exactly! So I have `2.4`, `3.1`,`0.2`

Comment: @user171558 so you are saying all the numeric values remain the same and only the non-numeric changed?

Comment: Well, at the end I would like to have everything being noted as 0 (no results),1 (negative),2 (positive).
Some fields have the actual test results in g/ml which were entered. If those are greater than 1.0, they should be considered positive. If lower than 1.0 Negative.

Comment: Just a warning that the `str_detect` approach used above for case 3 will return true for a note with a number in it, such as "a1". If that's possible, you might want to try `!is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(notes)))` instead, since any non-numeric characters will cause `as.numeric` to return an `NA` element.

Comment: @user171558 now the values are `2  
2   1  
3   1  
4   2  
5   2  
6   0  
7   2.4
8   3.1
9   0.2` If you can update your post or a new question, it is easier to crosscheck